# Getting error trying to increment a character's ASCII value by 1

Tags: python, ascii

I wanted to make a really small program that would convert the alphabet characters into ascii_values and vice versa but when it comes to incrementing the ascii value of the current character being processed an error is raised.

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Here is the code (Just the part that gets the error)

```
def character_to_ascii_value(char):
    print("The ASCII value of", char, "is:", ord(char))


character = "A"

for i in range(25):
    character_to_ascii_value(character)
    character = ord(character) + 1
```

PS: Searched it already but couldn't find out... (didn't get the other answers)

PS no2: I've found a solution but it's non pythonic... Converts this and that and back to adding it blah blah.. I think there must be something more simplistic

```
character = "A"
char_ascii = ord(character)

for i in range(25):
    character_to_ascii_value(character)
    char_ascii += 1
    character = chr(char_ascii)
```

Comment: The error says it all - `ord()` expects a character to give you its ascii table position (e.g. `ord("a")` will give you `97`), not a number that you're getting from your `range()` generator/list. You're not looking for its counterpart `chr()` (turns `97` to `"a"`) by any chance?

Comment: `character = chr(ord(character) + 1)` instead of `character = ord(character) + 1` inside the `for-loop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Shorter version

```
import string

for char in string.ascii_uppercase:
    print("The ASCII value of", char, "is:", ord(char))
```

### Original problem

Use `chr()` to convert the number into a string:

```
def character_to_ascii_value(char):
    print("The ASCII value of", char, "is:", ord(char))


character = "A"

for i in range(25):
    character_to_ascii_value(character)
    character = chr(ord(character) + 1)
```

Output:

```
The ASCII value of A is: 65
The ASCII value of B is: 66
The ASCII value of C is: 67
The ASCII value of D is: 68
The ASCII value of E is: 69
The ASCII value of F is: 70
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert back from the ASCII number to a `char`. Replace the last line with

```
character = chr(ord(character) + 1)
```